# moz-column-break-after polyfill?

Tags: html, css, firefox, multiple-columns

Firefox not natively supports this CSS3 Property:

```
break-after: column;
```

I'm searching for a break-after polyfill JS or a solution to break a css3 column to the next column after an element. Someone could help me in this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS Regions Polyfill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill) should do the trick. It provides unprefixed support for `break-after` and other CSS properties.

To use it, give an element the property:

```
 break-after: column;
```

then include the polyfill JS file.

Comment: I don't think this works for this use case. It makes it work for CSS Regions, but not CSS columns.